# Efficiently find connected components in undirected graph considering transitive equivalence

Tags: python, graph, computer-science, networkx, graph-theory

I have a set of nodes and a function `foo(u,v)` that can determine whether two nodes are equal. By "equal" I mean transitive equivalence:
 `If 1==2` and `2==3` then `1==3` and also: `If 1==2` and `1!=4` then `2!=4`

When given a set of nodes I can find all **connected components** in the graph by passing **every possible combination** of nodes to `foo(u,v)` (which returns predetermined results for presentation purposes only - **it is not the real function!**) function and building the needed edges. Like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def foo(u, v):
    # this function is simplified, in reality it will do a complex 
    # calculation to determine whether nodes are equal.
    EQUAL_EDGES = {(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (4, 5)}
    return (u, v) in EQUAL_EDGES


def main():
    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_nodes_from(range(1, 5 + 1))
    for u, v in itertools.combinations(g.nodes, 2):
        are_equal = foo(u, v)
        print '{u}{sign}{v}'.format(u=u, v=v, sign='==' if are_equal else '!=')
        if are_equal:
            g.add_edge(u, v)

    conn_comps = nx.connected_components(g)
    nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
    return conn_comps


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the problem with this approach  is that I get many redundant checks that I would like to avoid:

```
1==2  # ok
1==3  # ok
1!=4  # ok
1!=5  # ok
2==3  # redundant check, if 1==2 and 1==3 then 2==3 
2!=4  # redundant check, if 1!=4 and 1==2 then 2!=4 
2!=5  # redundant check, if 1!=5 and 1==2 then 2!=5
3!=4  # redundant check, if 1!=4 and 1==3 then 3!=4
3!=5  # redundant check, if 1!=5 and 1==3 then 3!=5
4==5  # ok
```

I want to avoid running in O(n^2) time complexity.
What is the correct way (or maybe an existing function in any python library) to efficiently find all connected components by a custom `foo(u,v)` function?

Comment: You cannot avoid `O(n^2)` complexity. All you can do is to avoid redundant comparisons

Comment: If the function `foo` computes the equality of two nodes by respecting transient equality among all nodes then why don't you have that function deal with redundancies in the first place? Or the other way round, how does that function ensure it respects transient equality among all nodes?

Comment: If the only thing you have access to is the blackbox function `foo`, then your problem is exactly that of finding connected components, and I think you can't do better than O(c n) where n is the number of vertices and c is the number of connected components. This complexity can be achieved using a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) This is good in case the number of components is small, but in the worst-case it's the same as O(n²).

Comment: However, if you can replace your function `foo(u, v)` that tests for equality, by a function `bar(u)` that generates a "class representative", so that `bar(u) == bar(v)` if and only if `foo(u, v) == True`, then you can find the connected components in linear time by storing the vertices into a dict of lists: `d = defaultdict(list); for u in g.nodes: d[bar(u)].append(u)`.

Comment: Actually in the case where all you have is a blackbox function `foo`, I mentioned union-find data-structure, but it's not even needed for an O(c n) complexity in your case, since `foo` defines equivalency classes (which means every connected component is fully connected). Just keep a list of connected components found so far, and compare each new vertex `u` with the first vertex of every connected component; add it to the first connected component it belongs to if there is one, or add it as a new connected component if not.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you're really trying to do, but here is a solution that checks only one element in each equivalent group:

```
nodes2place = range(1, 6)
cclist = []

for u in nodes2place:
    node_was_placed=False
    for icc in range(len(cclist)):
        if foo(u, cclist[icc][0]):
            cclist[icc].append(u)
            node_was_placed=True
            break

    # node doesn't fit into existing cc so make a new one
    if not node_was_placed:
        cclist.append([u])
```

Comment: this solution is still O(n^2) in worst case when there are no connections between nodes

Comment: Yes, its still O(n^2) in worst case, but its not clear to me if you can avoid that because of how you've phrased the equivalence relation search problem.  BTW, do you actually have an underlying graph structure or are you assuming you need one to find your components?  As you've asked the question, it looks like you're building a graph from the relation, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of which edges are transitively equal or unequal in two respective dictionaries. For each edge combination you can do a few simple checks in O(1) time to see if the calculation would be redundant. Otherwise you do the calculation from first principles and then, depending on whether the edges are equal or unequal, you update the above dictionaries with the necessary information. You'll still have to make C(n, 2) equality checks because that's how many combinations you iterate through, but for a bunch of them the decision may be made instantly.

The `equal_edges` dictionary is simpler to explain, so let's start with that. The 1-2 edge pair is equal, but since neither 1 or 2 exist as keys (the dict is empty for now), we create the set `{1, 2}` and attach it to both `equal_edges[1]` and `equal_edges[2]`. We then come across with the equal edge pair 1-3. Since `equal_edges[1]` now exists, we add 3 to its transitively equal nodes. But since this set is shared between both edges 1 and 2, it's updated in both places. We must also now attach this same set to `equal_edges[3]`. All three edges refer to the same set in memory, i.e., `{1, 2, 3}`, so we're not duplicating any data. Now when it comes to checking the equal edge pair 2-3, either `3 in equal_edges[2]` or `2 in equal_edges[3]` allows us to bypass any heavy calculations.

For the `unequal_edges` the logic is somewhat similar, but we must also refer to the `equal_edges` dictionary for transitively unequal edges. For example, the edge pair 1-4 is unequal. But since 1 is transitively equal to both 2 and 3, we must have `unequal_edges[4] = equal_edges[1]`. It would be redundant to set `unequal_edges[1] = {4}`, or `unequal_edges[2] = {4}`, etc. This is because this information can be obtained from `unequal_edges[4]`. It just means that for a transitively unequal pair a-b, we need to make a double check, i.e. `a in unequal_edges[b] or b in unequal_edges[a]`.

```
from itertools import combinations

equal_edges = {}
unequal_edges = {}

def update_equal_edges(a, b):
    def update_one(a, b):
        equal_edges[a].add(b)
        equal_edges[b] = equal_edges[a]
    exists_a = a in equal_edges
    exists_b = b in equal_edges
    if not (exists_a or exists_b):
        s = set((a, b))
        equal_edges[a] = s
        equal_edges[b] = s
    elif exists_a and not exists_b:
        update_one(a, b)
    elif exists_b and not exists_a:
        update_one(b, a)

def update_unequal_edges(a, b):
    exists_a = a in equal_edges
    exists_b = b in equal_edges
    if not (exists_a or exists_b):
        s = set((a, b))
        unequal_edges[a] = s
        unequal_edges[b] = s
    elif exists_a and not exists_b:
        unequal_edges[b] = equal_edges[a]
    elif exists_b and not exists_a:
        unequal_edges[a] = equal_edges[b]

def are_equal_edges(a, b):
    if a in equal_edges.get(b, []):
        print('{}=={} # redundant'.format(a, b))
        return True
    if (a in unequal_edges.get(b, [])) or (b in unequal_edges.get(a, [])):
        print('{}!={} # redundant'.format(a, b))
        return False
    # hardcoded equal edges which are the result
    # of some complex computations
    are_equal = (a, b) in {(1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5)}
    if are_equal:
        update_equal_edges(a, b)
    else:
        update_unequal_edges(a, b)
    print('{}{}{} # ok'.format(a, '==' if are_equal else '!=', b))
    return are_equal
```

The print statements are there for demonstration purposes. If you run

```
for a, b in combinations(range(1, 6), 2):
    are_equal_edges(a, b)
```

you get the following result

```
1==2 # ok
1==3 # ok
1!=4 # ok
1!=5 # ok
2==3 # redundant
2!=4 # redundant
2!=5 # redundant
3!=4 # redundant
3!=5 # redundant
4==5 # ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `0` to represent equality and `math.inf` to represent inequality as edge weights. Then for each node pair `u, v` you can compute the path length from `u` to `v` and based on the result decide whether the (heavy) node check needs to be invoked or not:

```
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(range(1, 6))
for u, v in it.combinations(g.nodes, 2):
    try:
        path = nx.shortest_path(g, u, v)
    except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
        new_weight = 0 if func(u, v) else math.inf
    else:
        weights = list(x['weight'] for x in it.starmap(g.get_edge_data, zip(path[:-1], path[1:])))
        if min(weights) == math.inf:
            new_weight = 0 if func(u, v) else math.inf
        elif max(weights) == math.inf:
            new_weight = math.inf
        else:
            new_weight = 0
    g.add_edge(u, v, weight=new_weight)
```

If you don't like these infinity edges in your graph then you can either:

- Remove them once the graph is constructed,
- or maintain a final graph in parallel to the infinity graph and in the end just keep the final one.